# Unity Tray Icons

Tags: 12.04, unity

I have been using Gnome Shell but recently tried working with Unity in 12.04. I have a couple of oddball apps whose tray icons don't work well regardless of theme (they must be missing transparency). Two apps Yammer and Jungledisk are the problem. If I can find the actual icons I could probably fix them. The icons in /usr/share/pixmaps don't match what I see in the tray. See the two icons right next to Skype.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that you cannot just fix the pixmaps, but would have to fix the code in the application that sets the color for the background of the tray icon. [A lot of applications have been reported with this kind of bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/checkgmail/+bug/403135) You probably should add those applications if there hasn't been a fix already released for later releases.

Comment: after a bunch of futzing with various them options, I managed to stabilize this... now if I could only figure out how to control indicator icon spacing :-)